# About Default Camera

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to open default iPhone Camara from my app using objective c?
Also, any possibilities to get capturing image or video which is selected from default camera when it's open from the native app?

Comment: yes it is possible to open default camera in Native app

Comment: how is it possible?Can you give me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open default camera application from your app. To get the camera into your application, you need to use [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller). It will do most of your task which you wanted to do.

Here is code to integrate it.

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    // You have the image. You can use this to present the image in the next view like you require in `#3`.

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

For capturing video:

```
      UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    [self.videoController setContentURL:self.videoURL];
    [self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];

    [self.videoController play];

}
```

Read [this apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html). There are 6 standard schemes: Mail, Phone, Text, Map, YouTube, iTunes. You cannot use them directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: what about video capturing @Nirmalsinh

Comment: But actually, I need to open iPhone default camera.

Comment: What you want to do with default Camera? Apple is not providing it.

Comment: I have put apple doc link. Apple is not providing direct access to use camera.

Comment: To avoiding to two methods for capturing video and image and also for using trying to apply apple feature.Thanks @Nirmalsinh

Comment: Apple won't provide direct access to use camera.  So we can do what apple give us for development.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is my answer useful to you?

Comment: Yes.It's really helped me.